# get latests posts from my wordpress on my webpage

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I am trying to get the latest posts on my blog. These are being displayed in a little widget in my front page on my website. I am getting a little trouble though. The posts are getting multiplied. http://goo.gl/Q2STSC, Here is my SQL query.

```
$posts = DB::connection('blog')->select("    
SELECT a.post_title AS title, a.post_name AS slug, meta_value AS thumbnail,a.post_content AS contenido, a.post_date AS fecha
FROM wp_postmeta, wp_posts AS a 
JOIN wp_posts AS b ON a.ID = b.post_parent
WHERE b.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
    AND meta_key = '_wp_attached_file' AND a.post_status = 'publish'
ORDER BY fecha
LIMIT 0 , 6");
```

Comment: Please explain why you are using a custom sql query. There are proper build in ways in wordpress to do this

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
<?php $args = array(
'posts_per_page'   => 6,
'offset'           => 0,
'orderby'          => 'date',
'order'            => 'DESC',
'post_type'        => 'post',
'post_status'      => 'publish'
 );
$posts_array = get_posts( $args ); 
 foreach ( $posts_arrayas $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
  <li>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
  </li>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Please use above code to fetch latest post from you blog.In above code you can see different parameters

posts_per_page :  Number of post to get
offset         :  Starting Post number likeyou do in custom query limit 0[offset],6[posts_per_page]
order          : Orderby [ DESC / ASC]
orderby        : date [ column on which order clause has to perform]
post_type      : post ( type of post] ( if you want to get posts for custom  posts like news, then you can pass news as post_type
post_status    : publish ( status of post )

Also in foreach you can permalink [ link of the post ] and the_title( title of the post)

For more details you can check here https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts

Comment: Please edit your answer to tell us why he should try this. How should he apply your suggestion? What will it change?

Comment: As per his post, he is trying to get latest post ,for that he is trying  custom query.. So I have suggested wp default function which will give same result as he is expecting.. He just need to copy this code and need to loop resulting array

Comment: Well, explain that in your answer then.

Comment: *Try this* is **not** a valid explanation to your code. What exactly is your code doing, how does it work, where must it be used. Your answer is lacking all of that. File an [edit] with all these requirements